# What is the purpose of the win32 CreateFile2 api call?

Tags: winapi, windows-8

They have added a new API call in windows 8 called `CreateFile2` which as far as I can tell does exactly the same as the existing `CreateFile` function only it packages up its parameters somewhat differently.

What has been added to make this necessary, as I can't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: `CreateFile2` can be used by store/metro app whereas `CreateFile` is for desktop apps only, so presumably there is some additional security auditing going in in the former

Comment: Well I thought that but then I thought that they wouldnt need a new function for that, it could just return a failure for things that weren't allowed when run on winrt.

Comment: @J99 "Need" isn't really what counts here. Perhaps they could have done it your way. But perhaps it was easier and cleaner to do it with a new function.

Answer (score 13):

`CreateFile` actually can do a lot more than just open a file. `CreateFile2` was created to both restrict the 'surface area' of the function to just the functionality allowed for UWP apps, -and- because the WACK tool can't really distinguish between 'good' use and 'bad' use of an import function, just that it is being used at all.

The typical pattern I use in my C++ libraries is as follows. I use an [RAII pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for the file handle to support when C++ Exception Handling is used (in addition to just being good [modern C++ coding practice](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-raii)):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory>

struct handle_closer
    { void operator()(HANDLE h) noexcept { assert(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE); if (h) CloseHandle(h); } };

using ScopedHandle = std::unique_ptr<void, handle_closer>;

inline HANDLE safe_handle(HANDLE h) noexcept { return (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ? nullptr : h; }
```

> The reason I have `safe_handle` is because `CreateFile` and `CreateFile2` are defined to return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1) instead of returning 0 for a failure. Most other Win32 functions that return handles return 0 for a failure, and I've confirmed that there's no case where a '0' is a valid Win32 handle.

For reading I use:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(
    CreateFile2(szFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING, nullptr)));
#else
ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(
    CreateFileW(szFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, nullptr)));
#endif
if (!hFile)
   // Error
```

> It is important to use `FILE_SHARE_READ` instead of 0 for the `dwShareMode` parameter for reading. UWP apps don't have exclusive read access to existing files, so calls would fail if you used 'exclusive' share mode (i.e. 0).

And for writing a file:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(
    CreateFile2(szFile, GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, nullptr)));
#else
ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(
    CreateFileW(szFile, GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE, 0, nullptr, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, nullptr)));
#endif
if (!hFile)
    // Error!
```

> For writing I request the `DELETE` permission because I use `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO` to clean up if the file output process fails. See [scoped.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/scoped.h#L35).

See [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](https://walbourn.github.io/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games-part-1/) for more information.

Comment: "It is important to use FILE_SHARE_READ instead of 0 for UWP applications" is a gem of an information.

Answer (score 6):

Due to the multiplexing of file creation flags, file attribute flags and
  security QoS flags into a single DWORD (dwFlagsAndAttributes) parameter for
  CreateFile, there is no way to add any more flags to CreateFile. Additional
  flags for the create operation must be added to CreateFile2 only. For example   FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REQUIRING_OPLOCK flag. This flag is documented [FltCreateFile - kernel mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541935(v=vs.85).aspx)